# how can I change user defined runtime attribute when button state change

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

[image: user defined runtime attribute]

I define some user defined runtime attribute like shadow in utilities

when button state change like normal to selected

how can I get rid of the shadow

help appreciated

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627724/uiview-shadow-using-user-defined-runtime-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the properties on the view like any other property.

```
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
layer.cornerRadius = someotherValue
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for help.. I'm not sure what you mean I have problem with setting the attribute when button is selected

Comment: @jin add a target selector for the state change event and change all these properties in that callback method